# Deserialize XML into Object

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Im trying to deserialize an xml response from from Amazons simple db service.

The xml is like this.

```
<ListDomainsResponse xmlns="http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-04-15/">
   <ListDomainsResult>
       <DomainName>Logging</DomainName>
       <DomainName>teets</DomainName>
   </ListDomainsResult>
   <ResponseMetadata>
      <RequestId>9d48122e-1ddf-8771-b771-b36599838ea0</RequestId>
     <BoxUsage>0.0000071759</BoxUsage>
   </ResponseMetadata>
</ListDomainsResponse>
```

And the object i'm trying to serialize into is this.

```
public class ListDomainsResponse  : Response
{
    public ListDomainsResult ListDomainsResult { get; set; }
}

public class ListDomainsResult
{
    public List<String> DomainNames { get; set; }

    public string NextToken { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public static string NameSpace = "http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-04-15/";

    public ResponseMetadata ResponseMetadata{ get; set; }
}

public class ResponseMetadata
{
    public string RequestId { get ; set; }

    public string BoxUsage { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that the response metadata is getting deserialized correctly but the List of strings called DomainName is not being deserialized, it is empty each time.

Can someone see what i'm doing wrong.

## Updated with more code

```
public async Task<Response> ListDomains (ListDomainsRequest request)
{
    using (Client = new HttpClient ()) {
        ListDomainsRequestMarshaller marshaller = new ListDomainsRequestMarshaller ();
        marshaller.Configure (request);
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = Client.GetAsync (marshaller.Marshal ()).Result;
        ListDomainsResponseUnMarshaller unmarshaler = new ListDomainsResponseUnMarshaller (responseMessage);
        return unmarshaler.Response;
    }
}

public ListDomainsResponseUnMarshaller (HttpResponseMessage message)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load (message.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync ().Result);

if (message.StatusCode.Equals (HttpStatusCode.OK)) {
    Serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(ListDomainsResponse), Response.NameSpace);
    Response = (ListDomainsResponse)Serializer.Deserialize (doc.CreateReader ());
    Response.HttpStatusCode = message.StatusCode;
    Response.ContentLength = (long)message.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
} else {
    Serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(Response));
    Response = (Response)Serializer.Deserialize (doc.CreateReader ());
    Response.HttpStatusCode = message.StatusCode;
    Response.ContentLength = (long)message.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
}
Serializer = null;
}
```

Comment: If you post the offending snippet of the generated proxy, we would be able to help you better.

Comment: As requested more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Attributes helped

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute (Namespace = "http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-04-15/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute ("ListDomainsResponse", Namespace = "http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-04-15/")]
public class ListDomainsResponse  : Response
{
    public ListDomainsResult ListDomainsResult { get; set; }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute (Namespace = "http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-04-15/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute (Namespace = "http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-04-15/")]
public class ListDomainsResult
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute ("DomainName")]
    public string[] DomainName { get; set; }

    public string NextToken { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Glad you were able to get this working.  Just one question.  Why didn't svcutil generate these attributes for you automatically?

Comment: Its REST not SOAP, I did how ever found a wsdl for their depreciated SOAP service which i used to generate a proxy and just c/p the attributes ;)